# Easy way to setup GitLab with existing Gitolite configuration

Tags: git, gitolite, gitlab

I have an existing Gitolite configuration with many users and repositories. It is setup in the default way as the Gitolite installation guide suggests.
Now I would like to add GitLab to be able to do code reviews and bug tracking.

What's the most convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: I just found about BitNami (http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab). They provide a one-click-installer (sort of) to setup GitLab. Does anyone have experience with this or did already migrate to BitNami/GitLab from a plain Gitolite environment?

Comment: Gitolite is no longer a part of GitLab (since version 5.0). They replaced it with GitLab shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer (January 2013)

You can follow the [standard installation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md), and indicate in your **[`gitlab.yml` config file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L106-L121)** the location of your gitolite repo, as well as the gitolite admin user.

However, GitLab requires from the user to register themselves in GitLab and copy their public ssh key.
That means you might need to adapt the way gitolite has stored existing gitolite users, since the name you have used is likely to be different than the name used by GitLab (it uses a name based on the `login_email_auuid`).

---

Update (August 2018, 5 years later):

As [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523876/easy-way-to-setup-gitlab-with-existing-gitolite-configuration/14524320#comment91175072_14524320) by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605586/thomas), a few months after this answer, GitLab [released GitLab 5.0, without gitolite](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/02/12/gitlab-without-gitolite/).

> Now I would like to add GitLab to be able to do code reviews and bug tracking.
>   What's the most convenient way to achieve this?

These days (2018, GitLab 11.2.x), code review is supported through **[merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html)** (it has been so since a few years already).
See:

- "[**Demo: Mastering code review with GitLab**](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/03/17/demo-mastering-code-review-with-gitlab/)" from [**Emily von Hoffmann**](https://twitter.com/emvonhoffmann),
- "**[Code Review Via GitLab Merge Requests](https://yalantis.com/blog/code-review-via-gitlab-merge-requests-code-review-must/)**" from **[Maxim Letushov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759685/maxim-letushov)**.

Comment: Seems gitlab does not use gitolite anymore. It has its own manager: gitlab-shell

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore. Gitlab does not use gitolite anymore.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think the question was asking how to migrate from gitolite to GitLab

Comment: @Thomas No: the question was: "Now I would like to add GitLab to be able to do code reviews and bug tracking. What's the most convenient way to achieve this?". That is what my update addresses.