# Modern way for interacting between gitlab and gitolite ; mounting filesystems

Tags: git, gitlab, gitolite, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

on a small Ubuntu LTS server we are running [gitolite (Version 2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128063824/http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/master-toc.html). 
Well I didn't want to change this running configuration up to now. 
Perhaps at next LTS upgrade we are going to migrate to gitolite v3.

Now I got the request, if I can "mal eben schnell" [german for "do it quickly and at once"] install GitLab with Continous Integration support to the same server.
After reading documentation, I know that "Starting from version 8.0, GitLab [Continuous Integration (CI) is fully integrated into GitLab itself](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/README.html)". Nice.
And I learnd that since GitLab 5.0, it is "[without gitolite](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/02/12/gitlab-without-gitolite/)".

After having a look into the [hardware requirements for GitLab CE Omnibus](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/install/requirements.html#hardware-requirements),
I can easily reject the "mal-eben-schnell" request with "no, not with this hardware".

But now my question is:

How can I setup GitLab (on a newer server) in a way, that I can manage our git repositories with gitolite AND that GitLab is the user WebGUI with wiki, tracking etc. to repositories controlled by gitolite without cloning or mirroring the gitolite repositories into gitlab repositories.

(From filesystems point of view: the repositories should stay at the same position for gitolite and GitLab.)

Yes, I found [this posting but I think the answer is not valid anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523876/easy-way-to-setup-gitlab-with-existing-gitolite-configuration) with newer GitLab Versions.

Answer (score 0):

You will find some article about [migrating from gitolite to GitLab](http://binaryadventures.com/blog/migrating-from-gitolite-to-gitlab/), but those are a "one-shot" operation.

You don't go back to or keep gitolite in sync.

Both can manage the ACL (Access Control Level) or your existing git repos (without moving them, since the [gitlab.yml config file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example) can simply reference the current git repos root path).

But you would need to script some kind of synchronization mechanism allowing for a GitLab user to be registered as well in your `gitolite-admin` repo, as this feature is not supported by default.